# check csv for blank fields and write output if exist blank

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, powershell-3.0, text-parsing

This is a csv example:

```
1- 2018-11-07,hostname-184,IP_INFO, 10.2334.40.334, 255.255.255.0, 
2 - 2018-11-07,hostname-184,IP_INFO, 334.204.334.68, 255.255.255.0,
3- 2018-11-07,hostname,7.1.79-8,IP_INFO, 142.334.89.3342, 255.255.255.0,
4- 2018-11-07,hostname,7.1.80-7,IP_INFO, 13342.221.334.87, 255.255.255.0, 
5- 2018-11-07,hostname-155,IP_INFO, 142.2334.92.212, 255.255.255.0, 
6 - 2018-11-07,hostname-184,IP_INFO, , , 1
7- 2018-11-07,hostname-184,IP_INFO, 10.19334.60.3343, 255.255.255.0,
```

so how can i check if the las two spaces are in blank (like line 6 ) ?

The idea is to use something like this:

```
    $contentdnsparsed = Get-Content $destination_RAW_NAS\DNS_NAS_PARSED_0 

For($i=0;$i -lt $contentdnsparsed.count;$i++){
if($contentdnsparsed[$i] -match "running")
    {

 $Global:MatchDNS = $OK } Else {$Global:MatchDNS = $FAIL }

    }
```

If match "something" in the space 4 and 5 after the "," output = OK else = FAIL.

Thank you guys

Comment: Your whole sample csv has no text `running` - so how could that work? I'd use `Import-Csv` and supply header names.

Comment: _if_ the lines are consistent with the pattern you show, then you can test for `-match ', , ,'` to id the line with missing data. that will match [or `-notmatch`] on three commas delimited by a single space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you give us a rather bad example of a CSV file, you should use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet.
Because the csv has no headers, you need to supply these with the `-Header` parameter like below:

```
$csvContent = Import-Csv -Path "$destination_RAW_NAS\DNS_NAS_PARSED_0" -Header @("Date","HostName", "InfoType","IPAddress","Subnet")
$csvContent | ForEach-Object {
    # test for empty IPAddress fields in the CSV
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.IPAddress)) {
        Write-Host "$($_.HostName) = FAIL" -ForegroundColor Red
        # somewhere in your code you have declared the variables $Global:MatchDNS, $FAIL and $OK I guess..
        $Global:MatchDNS = $FAIL
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$($_.HostName) = OK" -ForegroundColor Green
        $Global:MatchDNS = $OK
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` may work better here than `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: @BaconBits I disagree that `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` would be better here, because the whitespace in the csv is **not** enclosed in quote characters (as if it IS the fields value), and therefore it is 'eaten' by the `Import-Csv` cmdlet. It's effect wil be the same here.

Comment: Yeah, but if the file is ever field quoted because something changed upstream, the script will unexpectedly work differently. It's not like it's a well-documented, *guaranteed* behavior of Import-Csv; it's just an implementation detail. It's not like String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() should be avoided for performance or compatibility reasons, either. The bottom line is, "Do I ever want to treat a string that contains nothing but whitespace as though it were a valid IP address?" and that answer is going to be, "No, that's not ever going to be a valid IP address." So code for it.