# Issue : Output the same line over and over

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, powershell-4.0, text-parsing

Below is the code, the idea is to grab a raw output of a differents storage arrays, and parse them in to a csv, the last part of the function is a contribution from this link:

[check csv for blank fields and write output if exist blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231838/check-csv-for-blank-fields-and-write-output-if-exist-blank/53232131#53232131)

But when i output the information, the result is the same hostname writen over and over again, with the same results, using the same lines of the raw file but with only one host info.
The idea would be to have the output with the last check for each different host.

Something like this:

```
2018-11-13,host1,7.1.80-3,IP_INFO, 1023.6445.64.2513, 255.255.255.0, 1340.6565.6124.1, 1340.6565.6124.1,
2018-11-13,host2,7.1.80-3,IP_INFO, 1023.6445.64.2513, 255.255.255.0, 1340.6565.6124.1, 1340.6565.6124.1,No-Compliance
2018-11-13,host3,7.1.80-3,IP_INFO, 1023.6445.64.2513, 255.255.255.0, 1340.6565.6124.1, 101340.6565.6124.1,Compliance
2018-11-13,host4,7.1.80-3,IP_INFO, 1023.6445.64.2513, 255.255.255.0, 1340.6565.6124.1, 1340.6565.6124.1,Compliance

$OK = "Compliance"
$FAIL = "No-Compliance"
 function Parse_IP_NAS {

    #Write-Output "Date, Hostname,version, Config, Value, value 2, value 3, value 4 " | Out-File $finalpatch\outputip.txt -Encoding ASCII

        # "Network Information VNX"
    $contentnasip = ($ParseFileIP -split "`n") 

    For($i=0;$i -lt $contentnasip.count;$i++){

        if($contentnasip[$i] -match "Hostname:")
        {
            Write-Host "$infohostname,$infoipv4,$infonetmask,$gatewayinfo,$dnsinfo,$date"
            Write-Output "$date,$infohostname,IP_INFO,$infoipv4,$infonetmask,$gatewayinfo,$dnsinfo" | Out-File $destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED.txt -Append  -Encoding ASCII
            Write-Output "$date,$infohostname,IP_INFO,$infoipv4,$infonetmask,$gatewayinfo,$dnsinfo,$MatchDNS" | Out-File $destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_2.txt -Append  -Encoding ASCII

            #"Hostname Information"
            $global:infohostname = $contentnasip[$i+1]
        }

        elseif($contentnasip[$i] -match "IPv4 Address")
        {
            #"Ipv4 Address"
            $global:infoipv4 = ($contentnasip[$i]  -split "=")[1]
        }
        elseif($contentnasip[$i] -match "IPv4 Netmask")
        {
            #"Netmask Information"
            $global:infonetmask = ($contentnasip[$i] -split "=")[1]
        }
        elseif($contentnasip[$i] -match "IPv4 Gateway")
        {
            #"Gateway Information"
            $global:gatewayinfo = ($contentnasip[$i] -split "=")[1]
        }
        elseif($contentnasip[$i] -match "DNS Servers")
        {
           # "DNS Servers Information"
            $global:dnsinfo = ($contentnasip[$i] -split "=")[1]
        }   
    }

    $csvContent = Import-Csv -Path "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED.txt" -Header @("Date","Hostname","version","Config","Value","value 2","value 3","value 4")
    $csvContent | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output "$date,$infohostname,IP_INFO,$infoipv4,$infonetmask,$gatewayinfo,$dnsinfo,$MatchDNS" | Out-File $destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_3.txt -Append  -Encoding ASCII
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Value)) {
            Write-Host "$($_.HostName) = FAIL" -ForegroundColor Red

            $Global:MatchDNS = $FAIL
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "$($_.HostName) = OK" -ForegroundColor Green
            $Global:MatchDNS = $OK

        }
    }
```

Output ( $destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED.txt ) :

```
2018-11-07,host1-CS0,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 10.143.17.205, 255.255.254.0, 10.13443.16.15, 1299.493.100.1342,199.52342.1724.12341
2018-11-07,host2,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 101.20432.40.6512, 255.255.255.0, 130.2104.4034.1, 10.146.11.58,10.146.11.74,202343.2234.12340.37
2018-11-07,host3,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 120.204.430.658, 255.255.255.0, 10.20344.40.1, 10.146.11.58,10.14436.11.7234,203.2342.12340.37
2018-11-07,host4,7.1.79-8,IP_INFO, 1412.2221.89.1432, 255.255.255.0, 141232.212321.81239.254, 142.221.921.223,13499.2349.100.12
2018-11-07,host5,7.1.80-7,IP_INFO, 1452.2421.922.817, 255.255.255.0, 141232.2421.9122.2514, 142.221.119.92,142.221.119.91
2018-11-07,host6,8.1.9-155,IP_INFO, 1242.22211.92.21232, 255.255.255.0, 14232.2231.942.2524, 142.221.119.92,142.2321.1149.91
2018-11-07,host7,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 130.1392.423.2144, 255.255.255.0, 4210.19412.324.1, 101.14246.11.58,10.1414 62.131.744,2033.22.104.37
2018-11-07,host8,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 12310.12395.560.4213, 255.255.255.0, 110.191245.61240.241, 11240.12446.111.4258,1240.12446.2411.2474,20243.12.110.3427
2018-11-07,,,IP_INFO, 10.123.444.1, 25515.255.255.0, 10.195.60.1, 11230.14216.111.51248,10124.142416.14211.7424,212403.21.1240.3247
2018-11-07,host9,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 110.123.443.51, 255.255.255.0, 10124.11250.042.124, 11230.22312.2320.542,1042.21212.142129.2414
```

The idea:

```
2018-11-07,host1-CS0,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 10.143.17.205, 255.255.254.0, 10.13443.16.15, 1299.493.100.1342,199.52342.1724.12341, compliance
2018-11-07,host2,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 101.20432.40.6512, 255.255.255.0, 130.2104.4034.1, 10.146.11.58,10.146.11.74,202343.2234.12340.37, compliance
2018-11-07,host3,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 120.204.430.658, 255.255.255.0, 10.20344.40.1, 10.146.11.58,10.14436.11.7234,203.2342.12340.37, compliance
2018-11-07,host4,7.1.79-8,IP_INFO, 1412.2221.89.1432, 255.255.255.0, 141232.212321.81239.254, 142.221.921.223,13499.2349.100.12, compliance
2018-11-07,host5,7.1.80-7,IP_INFO, 1452.2421.922.817, 255.255.255.0, 141232.2421.9122.2514, 142.221.119.92,142.221.119.91 , compliance
2018-11-07,host6,8.1.9-155,IP_INFO, 1242.22211.92.21232, 255.255.255.0, 14232.2231.942.2524, 142.221.119.92,142.2321.1149.91 , compliance
2018-11-07,host7,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 130.1392.423.2144, 255.255.255.0, 4210.19412.324.1, 101.14246.11.58,10.1414 62.131.744,2033.22.104.37 , compliance
2018-11-07,host8,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 12310.12395.560.4213, 255.255.255.0, 110.191245.61240.241, 11240.12446.111.4258,1240.12446.2411.2474,20243.12.110.3427 , compliance
2018-11-07,,,IP_INFO, 10.123.444.1, 25515.255.255.0, 10.195.60.1, 11230.14216.111.51248,10124.142416.14211.7424,212403.21.1240.3247 , compliance
2018-11-07,host9,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 110.123.443.51, 255.255.255.0, 10124.11250.042.124, 11230.22312.2320.542,1042.21212.142129.2414 , compliance










 This is the example of $ParseFileIP





Hostname:
    host1-CS0,8.1.9-184
    Network:
    IPv4 Address            = 1.1.1.1.1
    IPv4 Netmask            = 255.255.254.0
    IPv4 Gateway            = 1.1.1.1.1
    DNS Servers             = 1.1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1.1
    Hostname:
    Host2,8.1.9-184
    Network:
    IPv4 Address            = 1.1.1.1.1
    IPv4 Netmask            = 255.255.255.0
    IPv4 Gateway            = 1.1.1.1.1
    DNS Servers             = 1.1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1.1
    Hostname:
    Host3,8.1.9-184
    Network:
    IPv4 Address            = 1.1.1.1.1
    IPv4 Netmask            = 255.255.255.0
    IPv4 Gateway            = 1.1.1.1.1
    DNS Servers             = 1.1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1.1
```

Comment: where is `$ParseFileIP` & `$infohostname,$infoipv4,$infonetmask,$gatewayinfo,$dnsinfo,$date` & `$MatchDNS1` ... and LOTS of other stuff coming from? [*frown*]

Comment: Can you add your input data and desired result?

Comment: This time, the question is WAY too unclear.. Show us where the different variables come from, especially `$ParseFileIP`. Values like `1023.6445.64.2513` can never be valid IP4v4 addresses, so what are they?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I don't think that the other stuff is important, this function import a raw output and then parse all the info in a csv, the idea is check that csv and if match a IP adress output "compliance" at the end of each line, if you need something else i can show you, thanks

Comment: @MikeTwc done, at the end of the file you can find the parsed information and the idea, thank you

Comment: @Theo maybe it's unclear, the important thing are not the IP address, this is dummy data only to explore the function, i can't ( for security reasons) expose the reals IP, only need to understand how can i write the output for each host, thanks

Comment: @Agustinlacorazza - so ... if it is not important ... strip out the needless stuff and introduce a TESTABLE bit of code. right now, the code depends on the exact contents of `$ParseFileIP` and we have no way to see what that will contain.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey okay, added the raw information, what would be $ParseFileIP, at the end of the file, and the parsed output, and then the expected output, what i need is to check the line value of the csv and the output at the end of each line the word "compliance" if it's not in blank.

Comment: @Agustinlacorazza - kool! [*grin*] now, what do you mean by `check the line value of the csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if your function `Parse_IP_NAS` creates a file called `IP_NAS_PARSED.txt` that looks like this:

```
2018-11-07,host1-CS0,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 10.143.17.205, 255.255.254.0, 10.13443.16.15, 1299.493.100.1342,199.52342.1724.12341
2018-11-07,host2,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 101.20432.40.6512, 255.255.255.0, 130.2104.4034.1, 10.146.11.58,10.146.11.74,202343.2234.12340.37
2018-11-07,host3,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 120.204.430.658, 255.255.255.0, 10.20344.40.1, 10.146.11.58,10.14436.11.7234,203.2342.12340.37
2018-11-07,host4,7.1.79-8,IP_INFO, 1412.2221.89.1432, 255.255.255.0, 141232.212321.81239.254, 142.221.921.223,13499.2349.100.12
2018-11-07,host5,7.1.80-7,IP_INFO, 1452.2421.922.817, 255.255.255.0, 141232.2421.9122.2514, 142.221.119.92,142.221.119.91
2018-11-07,host6,8.1.9-155,IP_INFO, 1242.22211.92.21232, 255.255.255.0, 14232.2231.942.2524, 142.221.119.92,142.2321.1149.91
2018-11-07,host7,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 130.1392.423.2144, 255.255.255.0, 4210.19412.324.1, 101.14246.11.58,10.1414 62.131.744,2033.22.104.37
2018-11-07,host8,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 12310.12395.560.4213, 255.255.255.0, 110.191245.61240.241, 11240.12446.111.4258,1240.12446.2411.2474,20243.12.110.3427
2018-11-07,,,IP_INFO, 10.123.444.1, 25515.255.255.0, 10.195.60.1, 11230.14216.111.51248,10124.142416.14211.7424,212403.21.1240.3247
2018-11-07,host9,8.1.9-184,IP_INFO, 110.123.443.51, 255.255.255.0, 10124.11250.042.124, 11230.22312.2320.542,1042.21212.142129.2414
```

and all you want is code that reads that `IP_NAS_PARSED.txt` to do a check on the existance if the IPv4 value and append a field after each line, I think all you have to do is this AFTER the `IP_NAS_PARSED.txt` is created:

```
# read the IP_NAS_PARSED.txt created by the 'Parse_IP_NAS' function and create a comma delimited .TXT file from it with the value '$MatchDNS' appended

# check if the file "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_3.txt" already exists. delete it if it does.
if (Test-Path -Path "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_3.txt") {
    Remove-Item -Path "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_3.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

$OK = "Compliance"
$FAIL = "No-Compliance"
$csvContent = Import-Csv -Path "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED.txt" -Header @("Date","Hostname","version","Config","IPv4","SubnetMask","Gateway","DNS1","DNS2")
$csvContent | ForEach-Object {
    # you can use IsNullOrEmpty() too in your case, but use 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace()' for safety if ever you decide to quote the values.
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.IPv4)) {
        $color = 'Red'
        $MatchDNS = $FAIL
    }
    else {
        $color = 'Green'
        $MatchDNS = $OK
    }

    # create a comma delimited line and show it in the console
    $newline = '{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}' -f $_.Date, $_.Hostname, $_.version, $_.Config, $_.IPv4, $_.SubnetMask, $_.Gateway, $_.DNS1, $_.DNS2, $MatchDNS
    Write-Host $newline -ForegroundColor $color

    # and add it to file "IP_NAS_PARSED_3.txt" manually (Add-Content wil create the file if it does not exist)
    $newline | Add-Content -Path "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_3.txt" -Force
}
```

<sup>Note: this code **follows** your function `Parse_IP_NAS` and is not meant to be inside that function.</sup>

---

**EDIT**

Maybe it is even a better idea to redo the `Parse_IP_NAS` function a bit, so we can streamline the parsing more efficiently and we don't need any 'in-between' files.

Just a thought, but how about this:

```
function Parse_IP_NAS {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByContent')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByContent')]
        [string]$Content,

        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByFileName')]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path
    )
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByFileName') {
        $Content = Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw
    }

    # create an array to store the resulting objects
    $result = @()
    # split the content of the "Network Information VNX" in $Content into blocks 
    # Each block starts with "Hostname:"
    foreach ($hostBlock in ($Content -split "Hostname:")) {
        # skip if we have nothing in the block
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($hostBlock)) { continue }

        # create a PSCustomObject with these properties:
        $parsedHost = '' | Select-Object 'Date','Hostname','Version','Config','IPv4','SubnetMask','Gateway','DNS1','DNS2','MatchDNS'

        ## I'm not sure where the Date came from.. Is that today's date?
        $parsedHost.Date   = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy\-MM\-dd')
        $parsedHost.Config = 'IP_INFO'

        # split the $hostBlock textblock on newlines (\r = CR, \n = LF) to get an array
        # loop through the lines, but skip the line 'Network:' and any possible empty or whitespace-only strings
        ($hostBlock -split '\r?\n') | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' -and $_ -notmatch 'Network:' } | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -match '=') {
                $value = ($_ -split '=')
                switch -regex ($value[0]) {
                    'IPv4 Address' { $parsedHost.IPv4 = $value[1].Trim() }
                    'IPv4 Netmask' { $parsedHost.SubnetMask = $value[1].Trim() }
                    'IPv4 Gateway' { $parsedHost.Gateway = $value[1].Trim() }
                    'DNS Servers'  { $parsedHost.DNS1, $parsedHost.DNS2 = ($value[1] -split ',') | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim()}}
                }
            }
            else {
                $parsedHost.Hostname, $parsedHost.Version = ($_ -split ',') | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
            }
        }

        # now check if the IPv4 value is set for this host
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($parsedHost.IPv4)) {
            $color = 'Red'
            $parsedHost.MatchDNS = 'No-Compliance'  # $FAIL
        }
        else {
            $color = 'Green'
            $parsedHost.MatchDNS = 'Compliance'     # $OK
        }

        # add the object to the $result array
        $result += $parsedHost

        # add some visual output to the console
        $message = '{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}' -f $parsedHost.Date, $parsedHost.Hostname, $parsedHost.Version, 
                                                                $parsedHost.Config, $parsedHost.IPv4, $parsedHost.SubnetMask, 
                                                                $parsedHost.Gateway, $parsedHost.DNS1, $parsedHost.DNS2, $parsedHost.MatchDNS
        Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor $color
    }
    return $result
}
```

Now you can execute the Parse_IP_NAS function to use either parameter 'Content' if you already have the content in a string variable like:

```
$parsedResult = Parse_IP_NAS -Content $ParseFileIP
```

Or feed it the full path and name of the file so it will read the content for you:

```
$parsedResult = Parse_IP_NAS -Path '<path to the Network Information VNX file>'
```

After this call to the function, we have an array of objects with all values for each host found in `$parsedResult` as objects, so this is where you choose what to do with this info:

**Scenario 1**
Create the output manually so it will become a file of comma delimited values without quotes around them:

```
$outputFile = "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_COMPLETE.txt"

# check if the output file already exists. delete it if it does.
if (Test-Path -Path $outputFile -PathType Leaf) {
    Remove-Item -Path $outputFile -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

# if you DO want headers in this file, uncomment the next line:
# Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value 'Date,Hostname,Version,Config,IPv4,SubnetMask,Gateway,DNS1,DNS2,MatchDNS'

# loop through the $parsedResult array and build a line for each object in there
$parsedResult | ForEach-Object {
    # create a comma delimited line and add it to the outputfile manually
    # (Add-Content wil create the file if it does not exist and default)
    $newline = '{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}' -f $_.Date, $_.Hostname, $_.Version, 
                                                            $_.Config, $_.IPv4, $_.SubnetMask, 
                                                            $_.Gateway, $_.DNS1, $_.DNS2, $_.MatchDNS
    $newline | Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Force
}
```

**Scenario 2**
Use PowerShells `Export-Csv` cmdlet and output the `$parsedResult` array as proper CSV file. The field values will have quotes around them.

```
$outputFile = "$destination_PARSE_NAS\IP_NAS_PARSED_COMPLETE.csv"
$parsedResult | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Delimiter ',' -Force
```

Comment: @Agustinlacorazza I have added some more code in my answer with an alternative `Parse_IP_NAS` function. It is just an idea I had to maybe streamline things a bit. Cheers!